# Order properties should not be accessed directly

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, customization

This code:

```
    foreach ($order->meta_data as $row) {
        if ($row->key == 'tid') {
            $tid = $row->value;
            break;
        }
    }
```

within the function

```
function function_name($order_id, $checkout = null) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        foreach ($order->meta_data as $row) {
            if ($row->key == 'tid') {
                $tid = $row->value;
                break;
            }
        }
    if (!empty($tid)) {
        ...
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'function_name');
```

triggers the PHP notice "**Order properties should not be accessed directly**" and I don't know what's the problem. I run Woocommerce 3.0.8 and Wordpress 4.8. Is it a bug or I do some mistake?

**Update:**

Fixed code looks like this:

```
foreach ($order->get_meta_data() as $row) {
    if ($row->key === 'tid') {
        $tid = $row->value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or even better:

```
$tid = $order->get_meta($key = 'tid');
```

More info from [Woocommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you shouldn't access `$order->meta_data` (and other properties) directly, but use the provided getter and setter functions.

In this case, use `$order->get_meta_data()`.

This method is (eventually) inherited from the `WC_Data` class.